# Monitor wakes-up from standby on Windows 10 when I haven't touched an input device

Tags: windows-10, display, power-management

It doesn't take long before the monitor wakes from standby after going to sleep (turning off); from 30 seconds to 4 mins.

I have a Zowie FK2 gaming mouse and a G920 steering wheel connected to the system. I suspect that 1 or both of those are intermittently generating slight movement events even when not touched and Windows 10 is interpreting them as the user returning and using those devices.

I've disabled the 'Allow this device to wake the computer' option for both devices in Device Manager but it had no effect (I suspect that option only governs waking the PC from sleep mode).

I've searched the web for a solution and found nothing.

Either of these solutions would resolve my issue:

- A solution which stops those 2 devices from ever waking up the monitor from sleep/standby.
- A solution which reduces the Windows 10 threshold of movement required from those devices in order for that movement to be considered as the user making the input.

Comment: AFAIR "Allow this device to wake the computer" means wake up the computer from stand-by mode not if only the monitor has entered powersave mode. I would suspect the gaming mouse. To my experience a high dpi mouse detects movement even if I touch my desk a little bit harder and far away from the mouse (my desk is rock solid and pretty heavy but the mouse still detects those extreme small movements). You can try to turn the mouse on it's back to disable it.

Comment: @Robert : cheers. Currently I'm just manually turning the monitor on and off, but I'm looking for a solution which involves no manual work. I may actually have my own solution in the works right now. I'm looking into using the AutoIt BlockInput function: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/BlockInput.htm